# Can I have CC Library colors automatically updated in library graphics?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-library

I have added colors from Illustrator to a new CC Library I created.

Next, I have added logos and many graphics which get re-used all the time.

If I updated a color in my library, can I get it to automatically update all the colors where they are used in the graphics in my library?

Or do I have to edit each library graphic and update it myself?

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to get Library items to reference one another -- But perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Alright, I think that's the answer then. I certainly can't find anything in the documentation that suggests I can do this.